# How to download file from iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoahttpserver

My application want to run one http server and other devises can download files from it.

I am using cocoa http server and follow: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/blob/master/Samples/DynamicServer/MyHTTPConnection.m

My http connection is:

```
@implementation MyHTTPConnection

- (NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path
{

    NSString *filePath = [self filePathForURI:path];

    // Convert to relative path

    NSString *documentRoot = [config documentRoot];

    NSString *relativePath = [filePath substringFromIndex:[documentRoot length]];

    NSLog(@"file path is %@", filePath);

    //return [super httpResponseForMethod:method URI:path];
    return [[HTTPFileResponse alloc] initWithFilePath:filePath forConnection:self];
}
@end
```

And the code in Delegate is :

```
        httpServer = [[HTTPServer alloc] init];

        [httpServer setConnectionClass:[MyHTTPConnection class]];


        [httpServer setType:@"_http._tcp."];
        NSString *webPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"web"];
        if(webPath){
            NSString * ip = '192.168.1.10';

            int port = 3321;
            [httpServer setDocumentRoot:webPath];
            [httpServer setPort:port];
            [httpServer setInterface: ip];
            [self startServer]; 
        }
```

When I download the test file in web document , the size is always o bytes.